# More efficiently computing probabilities

Tags: python, python-2.7, probability, repeat, coding-efficiency

I'm struggling with some coding-inexperience. The code I've written below, is extremely inconvenient and ugly to look at.

My question to you is: 
How can this be done more efficiently? The way I've chosen to do it, is rather inefficient. Pay attention to the `def freq_2dice(n, N):` section of the code, as well as the `print` statements. Those are the areas in which I need more efficiency as well as just nicer looking code.

Thanks!

EDIT: The assignment is to create a function which records and stores each of the probabilities of getting each of the possible sums when throwing 2 dice, `n` times.

The rest of the code is comparing those probabilities to the exact probabilities.

EDIT2: Error in code

```
from random import randint
import sys

def freq_2dice(n, N):
    M, A, E, R, T, Y, U, I, O, P, D = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    for reps in xrange(N):
        s = 0
        for dice in xrange(n):
            outcome = randint(1, 6)
            s += outcome
        if s==2:
            M += 1
        if s==3:
            A += 1
        if s==4:
            E += 1
        if s==5:
            R += 1
        if s==6:
            T += 1
        if s==7:
            Y += 1
        if s==8:
            U += 1
        if s==9:
            I += 1
        if s==10:
            O += 1
        if s==11:
            P += 1
        if s==12:
            D += 1
    return N*(float(M)/N), N*(float(A)/N), N*(float(E)/N), N*(float(R)/N), N*(float(T)/N), N*(float(Y)/N), N*(float(U)/N), N*(float(I)/N), N*(float(O)/N), N*(float(P)/N), N*(float(D)/N)

def chance_die():
    frequencies = {}
    for s in range(2, 13):
        frequency = 0
        for die1 in range(1, 7):
            for die2 in range(1, 7):
                if die1 + die2 == s:
                    frequency += 1
        frequencies[s] = frequency
    return frequencies


n = int(sys.argv[1])
N = int(sys.argv[2])

print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[0], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[2]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[1], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[3]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[2], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[4]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[3], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[5]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[4], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[6]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[5], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[7]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[6], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[8]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[7], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[9]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[8], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[10]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[9], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[11]/.36)
print 'No. of twos: %d, probability: %.2f, expected: %.2f' % (freq_2dice(n, N)[10], freq_2dice(n, N)[0]/(N/100), chance_die()[12]/.36)

'''

MacBook-Air:python Leroy$ python freq_2dice.py 2 100000
No. of twos: 2680, probability: 2.80, expected: 2.78
No. of threes: 5612, probability: 5.51, expected: 5.56
No. of fours: 8169, probability: 8.43, expected: 8.33
No. of fives: 11099, probability: 10.96, expected: 11.11
No. of sixes: 13827, probability: 13.91, expected: 13.89
No. of sevens: 16610, probability: 16.51, expected: 16.67
No. of eights: 13808, probability: 13.72, expected: 13.89
No. of nines: 10947, probability: 11.22, expected: 11.11
No. of tens: 8249, probability: 8.35, expected: 8.33
No. of elevens: 5540, probability: 5.59, expected: 5.56
No. of twelves: 2805, probability: 2.74, expected: 2.78

'''
```

Comment: You probably want a list (array) instead of using variables M, A, ... P, D.

Comment: Well, for one, you could replace all of the `if` statements with a `dict`, e.g. `s_values_dict = {2: 'M', 3: 'A', 4: 'E', 5: 'R', ...}` Then you could just reference whatever key in the dictionary instead of having all of those `if`s.

Comment: I tried doing that. Making it a `dict`, however I didn't know how to implement `n` and `N` in that function. As in `xrange(n)` and `xrange(N)` I simply didn't know how to write it.

Comment: If this is a homework, how about asking this to your teacher?

Comment: It is indeed. He's not answering, and I thought I'd seek help here. 
Just discovered the site, and thought it'd be a good place to learn coding, as well as being a part of a coding community. Don't know if this is the right place for people without sufficient coding experience, but I liked the concept of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `N` in the second loop, it looks like it should be `n`, i.e. `100000` runs of throwing `2` dice.
You really don't need all of the variables, you just want to count up the scores, use a `dict` with the score as a key.
You are calling `freq_2dice()` for each `print`, which means `N*n` calls for each print. You should just call it once:

```
result = freq_2dice(n, N)
print ... result[0] ...
print ... result[1] ...
...
```

There are a numbers of areas that assumes 2 dice, despite the number of dice being an argument.

An example using a `dict` to keep `{score: count}`:

```
from random import randint

def freq_ndice(n, N):
    d = {}
    for _ in range(N):
        score = sum(randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n))
        d[score] = d.get(score, 0) + 1
    return d
```

But finally you can simplify frequency calculation a lot with `collections.Counter()` which is a form of `dict` that counts up the occurrences of things:

```
from collection import Counter

def freq_ndice(n, N):
    return Counter(sum(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)) for _ in range(N))

>>> n, N = 2, 100000
>>> for score, count in freq_ndice(n, N).items():
...     print('No. of {}s: {}, probability: {:.2f}%'.format(score, count, 100*count/N))
No. of 2s: 2870, probability: 2.87%
No. of 3s: 5533, probability: 5.53%
No. of 4s: 8386, probability: 8.39%
No. of 5s: 11081, probability: 11.08%
No. of 6s: 13947, probability: 13.95%
No. of 7s: 16649, probability: 16.65%
No. of 8s: 13850, probability: 13.85%
No. of 9s: 11166, probability: 11.17%
No. of 10s: 8166, probability: 8.17%
No. of 11s: 5496, probability: 5.50%
No. of 12s: 2856, probability: 2.86%
1 loop, best of 3: 900 ms per loop
```

Note: Python3... use `xrange`, `from __future__ import print_function` and `100.0` in Python2

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! 

I already edited the `N` to `n`, but I guess you were writing you answer when I did that.

What you just did seems like a great solution, I just don't know quite how ti implement it in my code rather than my inconvenient heaps of unnecessary code. I'm quite new. 

Care to explain further? Or is that too much to ask?

EDIT: Oh, btw, I did try making a dictionary to count the scores, I however failed. I didn't see where I would implement `N` and `n` in the function where I defined the dict.

Comment: @FrenziedMango Restructured the answer, perhaps more comprehensible. Happy to address any other questions. Note: `_` is just a convention in python to indicate an unused variable you could use any variable name, e.g. `i`